# How to get my user id and posts from username on Instagram?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Due to recent changes on API Instagram, it is not possible to use the endpoint above:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

I've tried with:

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=username
```

However, it is not working correctly to fetch data. Please, could someone help to find a solution?

In advance, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=username` does in fact work if the client has the `X-IG-App-ID` request header set. This header value can be obtained by inspecting the request sent via any web browser.

Comment: But it doesn't work with fetch in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Try with this endpoint if your account is a business account.

[https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields={id,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username}&access_token=""](https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=%7Bid,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username%7D&access_token=%22%22)